# Index is not called successfully after creating and saving

Tags: php, laravel, routes

It is said that there are few arguments, but I do not know what is wrong
**ProjectContorller.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cats = Category::all();
    $users = User::all();
    $view = Project::where('status', '!=', 'Complete')->get();
    return view('project.index', compact('view', 'cats', 'users'));
}  
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $project = new Project;
    $project->fill($request->all())->save();
    return ProjectController::index();
}
```

The error message is like this

```
Too few arguments to function app\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::index(), 0 passed in
```

Comment: do you mean to go back to `index`? maybe you mean to `redirect` to index, not invoke the actual method

Comment: `index` takes a parameter which is Request, you are passing nothing hence the error. See @Kevin's comment.

Comment: @su3158 Why do you need `$request` in `index()` when you are not doing anything with it at all?

Comment: @su3158 Also,  `return $this->index();` seems much better to me than `return ProjectController::index();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is occurring because `index` takes a parameter (`Request`) and you aren't passing anything to it.

To solve the issue, you need to use [redirect](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-redirect) instead of trying to call the controller function directly:

```
return redirect()->route('<route-name>');
```

or

```
return redirect('<path>')
```